# writing an initialized static hashtable elegantly

Tags: java, hashtable

Is there a way to write a static final Hashtable in java in key value pairs just like you can initialize a string array conveniently as :

```
String [] foo = {"A","AB"};
```

Basically what I mean is not having to write the words "put" for key:value pairs but instead may be something like:

```
Hashtable<String, String> foo = {"JJ":"222","KK":"222"}
```

which IMO looks more elegant.

(I know the initialization would need to be in a static block. I am leaving that out for now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Java doesn't have map literals, but it does have array literals.

```
static final Map<String, String> map;

static {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[][] pairs = {
        {"foo", "bar"},
        {"x", "y"}
    };
    for (String[] pair : pairs) {
        map.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't really add anything to the straightforward *copy and paste `put`* solution, and it doesn't work well if your key and value types aren't the same.

Answer (score 10):

An anonymous inner class would give you double brace initialization, which is useful in some cases:

```
static final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("foo", "bar");
    put("x", "y");
}};
```

In any case, @michael667's answer is probably the best

Comment: Preferred solution: Moves the initial code right underneath the static variable. No matter what you do with source code auto formatting (Sort Members). Only uses pure standard java libs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use guava's [ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
map = ImmutableMap.of(key1, value1, key2, value2);
```

These convenience methods exist for one to five elements. If you need more, you can use an [ImmutableMap.Builder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html):

```
static final ImmutableMap<String, Integer> WORD_TO_INT =
   new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Integer>()
     .put("one", 1)
     .put("two", 2)
     .put("three", 3)
     .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

No, you're looking for something like C#'s [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), which doesn't currently exist in Java.

You can use an anonymous class to save a little typing, but you still have to write `put`.